# Input is `null`. How can I calculate the input value with date?

Tags: javascript, html, date

Input is `null`. How can I calculate the input value with date?

[image]

```js
/* // ========================================================
* *
* * * I Want To Calculate Input Value With Date, Input Is null
* *
*/ // ========================================================

var time     = new Date();
var realTime = time.toLocaleString();
var hours    = time.getHours();
var minutes  = time.getMinutes();

var input = document.getElementById("input");
// Value of input 20:00 => output of this input is null.

var divOfOutput = document.getElementById("output");

divOfOutput.innerHTML = (hours - input) + ":" + (minutes - input);
// Calculation Not Done, Output Just Real Time

console.log(realTime);
console.log((hours - input) + ":" + (minutes - input));
```

```html
    <input id="index" type="time" value="20:00">
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: How do you check for the input? What precisely is `null`? Also, why are you attempting to subtract an _object_ from a number? `(hours - input) + ":" + (minutes - input)` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Your input has the id `index` but you are checking for `input` in your `getElementById` call.

Comment: `id="index"` should be `id="input"`. Just fix that typo.

Comment: 1.) Use the same id attribute value on the element and in JS ( mismatch 'input'/'index' ); 2.) `input` contains the DOM node, you need the value  - use `input.value` instead. 3.) You need to split `input`'s value into hours and minutes, eg. using `input.value.split(/:/)`. 4.) The differences you compute appear to be meaningless, eg. they do not cater for carry overs - is that just a proof of concept on having js code interact with the DOM  ?

Comment: It’s likely better to use `time.toString()` rather than `LocaleString()` without options as the former tends to be unambiguous (and will be by specification in ECMAScript 2019), whereas the default for *toLocaleString* has no such constraint. Every browser I have installed does not use my system settings for the format, they us the peculiar en-US format instead. So while I might hope to see 8/7/2018, I get 7/8/2018 instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code below sports some basic modifications to get the code straight. It is not completely evident (to me at least) what you are trying to achieve, though.

Issues addressed:

1. id attribute in html and must match
2. Difference between the input element (DOM Node) and its content (the value)
3. Extracting hours and minutes from the input data
4. Making sure to have positive differences only

ToDo (at least):

5. carry over to have a meaningful difference between the current time and the data from the input field

```js
// Rectifying the obvious mistakes.
 
var time     = new Date();
var realTime = time.toLocaleString();
var hours    = time.getHours();
var minutes  = time.getMinutes();

var input = document.getElementById("input"); // 1. Same id attribute as in html
let a_input = input.value.split(/:/); // 2. take the value, not the element; 3. split into hours and minutes

var divOfOutput = document.getElementById("output"); 

divOfOutput.innerHTML = ((hours - a_input[0] + 24) % 24) + ":" + ((minutes - a_input[1] + 60) % 60); // 4. Make sure to have positive deltas only even when crossing midnight or the full hour


console.log(realTime);
console.log(((hours - a_input[0] + 24) % 24) + ":" + ((minutes - a_input[1] + 60) % 60));
```

```html
    <input id="input" type="time" value="20:00"><!-- 1. same  id attribute as in code -->
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help to me